# How can I logout another user in Yii2

Tags: session, yii2

I need to be able to logout other users. I tried the following:

```
Yii::$app->getSession()->destroySession($sessionId)
```

I do this for every sessionId connected to this user.

I tried changing the authKey (with enableAutoLogin set to true).
Setting enableAutoLogin to false doesn't help.

The session is deleted in the database but as soon as that user does a new request his session, with the same sessionId as before, appears in the database again.

I tried using this:

```
Yii::$app->user->switchIdentity(User::findIdentity($id), 0);
Yii::$app->user->logout(true);
```

The switchIdentity works but creates a new session in the database (that i destroy with the logout method).

As a test I have downloaded both the basic and advanced template and both have the same problem. What am I missing here ?

I tried doing the same in pure PHP but somehow Yii manages to get the user session back and the user is still logged in.

I am using Yii 2.0.6

Comment: try creating `authKey` in `actionlogin()` .

Comment: I am already doing that

Comment: show little more code where you started `session`.

Comment: Are you sure that Yii gets the same session back with the same session ID? I really doubt that. Maybe it is creating another session right away. Could be the auto login feature? Which would then work as expected.

Comment: just found out that when i remove this from my config everything works as expected:
'readCallback'  => function ($fields) {
          return [
            'expireDate' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($fields['expire']),
      },